# How to drop a list of rows from Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df :

```
>>> df
                  sales  discount  net_sales    cogs
STK_ID RPT_Date                                     
600141 20060331   2.709       NaN      2.709   2.245
       20060630   6.590       NaN      6.590   5.291
       20060930  10.103       NaN     10.103   7.981
       20061231  15.915       NaN     15.915  12.686
       20070331   3.196       NaN      3.196   2.710
       20070630   7.907       NaN      7.907   6.459
```

Then I want to drop rows with certain sequence numbers which indicated in a list, suppose here is `[1,2,4],` then left:

```
                  sales  discount  net_sales    cogs
STK_ID RPT_Date                                     
600141 20060331   2.709       NaN      2.709   2.245
       20061231  15.915       NaN     15.915  12.686
       20070630   7.907       NaN      7.907   6.459
```

How or what function can do that ?

Comment: just to clarify, this question is about dropping rows with specific index values.. their use of [1,2,4] is to point to the rows *left over* after dropping. There are answers below that do this.

Answer (score 520, accepted):

Use [DataFrame.drop](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and pass it a Series of index labels:

```
In [65]: df
Out[65]: 
       one  two
one      1    4
two      2    3
three    3    2
four     4    1
    
    
In [66]: df.drop(index=[1,3])
Out[66]: 
       one  two
one      1    4
three    3    2
```

Comment: +1 In addition, Dropping the last row df.drop(df.tail(1).index)

Comment: This answer only works if df.index.unique() is the same as df.index, which is not a requirement for a Pandas DataFrame.  Does anyone have a solution when df.index values are not guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: this doesnt allow you to index on the index name itself

Comment: Folks, in examples, if you want to be clear, please don't use the same strings for rows and columns. That's fine for those who really know their stuff already. Frustrating for those trying to learn.

Comment: how can you do this with a range of rows? say from row 0 to row n.

Comment: newcomers to python: note that if you want to drop these rows and save them in the same dataframe (inplace) you also need to add the `axis=0` (0 = rows, 1 = columns) and `inplace=True` as in `df.drop(df.index[[1,3]], axis=0, inplace=True)`.  @mezzanaccio, if you specifically know which indexes you want to replace (and also using your 0 to n example):`df.drop(df.index[range(0, n)], axis=0, inplace=True)`

Comment: @YuryBayda `ix` has been [deprecated, see this for a replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43838999/pandas-replacement-for-ix)

Comment: @JJones In this case, I find that I can achieve the effect if I reset_index() to change the index to the default integer index, then drop() the relevant row indexes, then set_index() to change the index back to the original index column. I can't find any documentation that the default integer index is [0, 1, ...] or that it's unique, though.

Comment: Am I wrong or does the index start with 0 as in danielhadar's answer below `df.drop(df.index[0])`, which would mean this answer would drop the second and forth rows? Ah, yes, it does, and that is what the answer shows.. right. Not the clearest example, but correct. I would have used maybe [1,2] to point this out.

Comment: It gives me a warning SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Answer (score 156):

Note that it may be important to use the "inplace" command when you want to do the drop in line.

```
df.drop(df.index[[1,3]], inplace=True)
```

Because your original question is not returning anything, this command should be used.
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Answer (score 78):

If the DataFrame is huge, and the number of rows to drop is large as well, then simple drop by index `df.drop(df.index[])` takes too much time.

In my case, I have a multi-indexed DataFrame of floats with `100M rows x 3 cols`, and I need to remove `10k` rows from it. The fastest method I found is, quite counterintuitively, to `take` the remaining rows.

Let `indexes_to_drop` be an array of positional indexes to drop (`[1, 2, 4]` in the question).

```
indexes_to_keep = set(range(df.shape[0])) - set(indexes_to_drop)
df_sliced = df.take(list(indexes_to_keep))
```

In my case this took `20.5s`, while the simple `df.drop` took `5min 27s` and consumed a lot of memory. The resulting DataFrame is the same.

Comment: Wouldn't it be cheaper to just negate a mask rather than creating a set? Something like `m = np.ones(len(df), bool); m[indices_to_drop] = False`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist that should probably be more efficient, thanks!

Comment: working on 50m+ rows. this is really fast ~2mins on the Fargate container.

Answer (score 51):

I solved this in a simpler way - just in 2 steps.

1. Make a dataframe with unwanted rows/data.
2. Use the index of this unwanted dataframe to drop the rows from the original dataframe.

Example:
Suppose you have a dataframe df which as many columns including 'Age' which is an integer. Now let's say you want to drop all the rows with 'Age' as negative number.

```
df_age_negative = df[ df['Age'] < 0 ] # Step 1
df = df.drop(df_age_negative.index, axis=0) # Step 2
```

Hope this is much simpler and helps you.

Comment: +1, this is the only answer that tells you how to remove a row selecting a column different from the first one.

Comment: This is the answer which I was looking. Thanks Krishnaprasad garu

Comment: Note that this can produce incorrect results if the index contains duplicate values

Answer (score 48):

You can also pass to [DataFrame.drop](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the *label itself* (instead of Series of index labels):

```
In[17]: df
Out[17]: 
            a         b         c         d         e
one  0.456558 -2.536432  0.216279 -1.305855 -0.121635
two -1.015127 -0.445133  1.867681  2.179392  0.518801

In[18]: df.drop('one')
Out[18]: 
            a         b         c         d         e
two -1.015127 -0.445133  1.867681  2.179392  0.518801
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
In[19]: df.drop(df.index[[0]])
Out[19]: 
            a         b         c         d         e
two -1.015127 -0.445133  1.867681  2.179392  0.518801
```

Comment: df.drop(df.index[0]) also works. i mean, no need for double square_brackets (with pandas 0.18.1, at least)

Answer (score 17):

If I want to drop a row which has let's say index `x`, I would do the following:

```
df = df[df.index != x]
```

If I would want to drop multiple indices (say these indices are in the list `unwanted_indices`), I would do:

```
desired_indices = [i for i in len(df.index) if i not in unwanted_indices]
desired_df = df.iloc[desired_indices]
```

Comment: This works for what I wanted, thanks! Drop all rows except index X. df = df[df.index == 'x']

Answer (score 13):

Here is a bit specific example, I would like to show. Say you have many duplicate entries in some of your rows. If you have string entries you could easily use string methods to find all indexes to drop.

```
ind_drop = df[df['column_of_strings'].apply(lambda x: x.startswith('Keyword'))].index
```

And now to drop those rows using their indexes

```
new_df = df.drop(ind_drop)
```

Answer (score 8):

Use only the Index arg to drop row:-

```
df.drop(index = 2, inplace = True)
```

For multiple rows:-

```
df.drop(index=[1,3], inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 3):

In a comment to @theodros-zelleke's answer, @j-jones asked about what to do if the index is not unique.  I had to deal with such a situation.  What I did was to rename the duplicates in the index before I called `drop()`, a la:

```
dropped_indexes = <determine-indexes-to-drop>
df.index = rename_duplicates(df.index)
df.drop(df.index[dropped_indexes], inplace=True)
```

where `rename_duplicates()` is a function I defined that went through the elements of index and renamed the duplicates.  I used the same renaming pattern as `pd.read_csv()` uses on columns, i.e., `"%s.%d" % (name, count)`, where `name` is the name of the row and `count` is how many times it has occurred previously.

Answer (score 3):

Determining the index from the boolean as described above e.g.

```
df[df['column'].isin(values)].index
```

can be more memory intensive than determining the index using this method

```
pd.Index(np.where(df['column'].isin(values))[0])
```

applied like so

```
df.drop(pd.Index(np.where(df['column'].isin(values))[0]), inplace = True)
```

This method is useful when dealing with large dataframes and limited memory.

Answer (score 3):

To drop rows with indices 1, 2, 4 you can use:

```
df[~df.index.isin([1, 2, 4])]
```

The tilde operator `~` negates the result of the method `isin`. Another option is to drop indices:

```
df.loc[df.index.drop([1, 2, 4])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the following dataframe df

> `df`

```
   column1  column2  column3
0        1       11       21
1        2       12       22
2        3       13       23
3        4       14       24
4        5       15       25
5        6       16       26
6        7       17       27
7        8       18       28
8        9       19       29
9       10       20       30
```

Lets drop all the rows which has an odd number in column1

Create a list of all the elements in column1 and keep only those elements that are even numbers (the elements that you dont want to drop)

> `keep_elements = [x for x in df.column1 if x%2==0]`

All the rows with the values `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]` in its column1 will be retained or not dropped.

```
df.set_index('column1',inplace = True)
df.drop(df.index.difference(keep_elements),axis=0,inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

We make the column1 as index and drop all the rows that are not required. Then we reset the index back.
`df`

```
   column1  column2  column3
0        2       12       22
1        4       14       24
2        6       16       26
3        8       18       28
4       10       20       30
```

Answer (score 2):

As [Dennis Golomazov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43421391/2988730) suggests, using `drop` to drop rows. You can select to keep rows instead. Let's say you have a list of row indices to drop called `indices_to_drop`. You can convert it to a mask as follows:

```
mask = np.ones(len(df), bool)
mask[indices_to_drop] = False
```

You can use this index directly:

```
df_new = df.iloc[mask]
```

The nice thing about this method is that `mask` can come from any source: it can be a condition involving many columns, or something else.

The really nice thing is, you really don't need the index of the original DataFrame at all, so it doesn't matter if the index is unique or not.

The disadvantage is of course that you can't do the drop in-place with this method.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an example dataframe

```
df =     
index    column1
0           00
1           10
2           20
3           30
```

we want to drop 2nd and 3rd index rows.

**Approach 1:**

```
df = df.drop(df.index[2,3])
 or 
df.drop(df.index[2,3],inplace=True)
print(df)

df =     
index    column1
0           00
3           30

 #This approach removes the rows as we wanted but the index remains unordered
```

**Approach 2**

```
df.drop(df.index[2,3],inplace=True,ignore_index=True)
print(df)
df =     
index    column1
0           00
1           30
#This approach removes the rows as we wanted and resets the index.
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
# Create a list containing the index numbers you want to remove
index_list = list(range(42766, 42798))
df.drop(df.index[index_list], inplace =True)
df.shape
```

This should drop all indexes within that created range