# Deleting rows of daylight saving time from a time indexed pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, time-series

I have written the following function to delete the rows for Daylight Saving Time in a pandas dataframe as not every column has data for the hour of switching:

```
def hrsDSTdelete (df):
    import pandas as pd    
    hrsDSTadjust = ['2000-03-26 02:00:00', ...  '2012-03-25 02:00:00', '2013-03-31 02:00:00']

    for DSTvalue in hrsDSTadjust:                          
        if DSTvalue in df.index :  
            df = df.drop(pd.Timestamp(DSTvalue)) 
            print 'DST hour: ', DSTvalue, " deleted!"         
    return df   
pass
```

As this seems to work when deleting single rows, the following error message occurs when trying to do it with this loop:

> exceptions.TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not iterable

I have tried also with

```
df =  df.ix[DSTvalue].drop
```

but this does not seem to delete the row in the dataframe.
Has anyone got an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661701/how-to-drop-a-list-of-rows-from-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that [`drop` takes an array-like argument `labels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), and you are only passing it a timestamp. You should be able to use a list comprehension instead of your loop too:

```
indices = [pd.Timestamp(DSTvalue) for DSTValue  in hrsDSTadjust if DSTvalue in df.index]
df = df.drop(indices)
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a loop, try this one:

```
df.drop(df.index[hrsDSTadjust])
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. Im getting this error message:  
exceptions.IndexError: unsupported iterator index