# Python pandas tz_localize throws NonExistentTimeError, then unable to drop erroneous times

Tags: python, pandas, timezone, dst

In python pandas, I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image]

For data before 2007-04-26 17:00:00, the time zone is US/Eastern. For data after, the time zone is American/Chicago.

When I run this:

```
data.index = data[:'2007-04-26 16:59:59'].index.tz_localize('US/Eastern', ambiguous = 'NaT').tz_convert('Europe/London')
```

I get an error that says:

```
NonExistentTimeError: 2006-04-02 02:00:00
```

This is indeed because of daylight savings time. I have the same problem for 2007. I don't have the  problem for subsequent years. Ideally, I'd like two commands - one that converts the first half of the dataset from Eastern to London, and another that converts the second half from Chicago to London.

Since that didn't work, I tried dropping these times (an hour I believe), eg. 02:00:00 to 03:00:00 where there was daylight savings time. However, when I run

```
data.drop(data.ix['2005-04-03 2:00:00':'2005-04-03 3:00:00'], inplace=True)
```

I get

```
ValueError: labels ['open' 'high' 'low' 'close' 'volume'] not contained in axis
```

Does anyone know how I can simply convert these times? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Alex

UPDATE to add more info:

[image]

Ok I've used the following code which has worked to drop the offending times:

UPDATE 2:

```
mask =  ((data.index<datetime.strptime("2006-04-02 02:00:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%S:%M")) | (data.index>datetime.strptime("2006-04-02 03:00:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%S:%M"))) & ((data.index<datetime.strptime("2005-04-03 02:00:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%S:%M")) | (data.index>datetime.strptime("2005-04-03 03:00:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%S:%M"))) & ((data.index<datetime.strptime("2005-10-30 01:00:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%S:%M")) | (data.index>datetime.strptime("2005-10-30 02:00:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%S:%M"))) & ((data.index<datetime.strptime("2006-10-29 01:00:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%S:%M")) | (data.index>datetime.strptime("2006-10-29 02:00:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%S:%M")))
data_filtered = data[mask]
data_filtered.ix = data_filtered.tz_localize('US/Eastern', infer_dst=True).tz_convert('Europe/London')
```

But now I get this error:

```
    data_filtered.ix = data_filtered.tz_localize('US/Eastern', infer_dst=True).tz_convert('Europe/London')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-38-0fc8a9e68588>", line 1, in <module>
    data_filtered.ix = data_filtered.tz_localize('US/Eastern', infer_dst=True).tz_convert('Europe/London')

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1955, in __setattr__
    object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Any ideas on this? I did some Googling but couldn't find anything really related..

Comment: can you post the row for "2006-04-02 02:00:00" and for some of the rows you are trying to drop? It seems that those data points are missing, and most probably because of DST as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your drop command doesn't look like it should work based on the description in the docs. To get rid of the offending times, I would create a mask on the dataframe, ie:

```
from datetime import datetime
mask =  ((df.index<datetime.strptime("2006-04-02 02:00:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%S:%M") | (df.index>datetime.strptime("2006-04-02 03:00:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%S:%M")) # probably add some    more years here as or clauses

df_filtered = df[mask]
```

Probably there's a way to make drop work too. Check this related question:
[Deleting rows of daylight saving time from a time indexed pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084662/deleting-rows-of-daylight-saving-time-from-a-time-indexed-pandas-dataframe?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks! This works to drop rows. A quick follow-up: I'm not really familiar with masks.. do you know how what syntax I can use to basically make it "and" other time windows that I want to omit? Is there a way more concise than adding a mask for each time window (eg. mask1, mask2, mask3)? Thanks again!

Comment: mask = ((df.foo<1)&(df.foo>-2)) is the general idea. Use | for or and & for and. If this helped you then please accept the question :)

Comment: Ok I plan to - do you think you could just take a look at my second update and see if you know the solution? I just really want to fix this DST issue so I can actually work with my dataset

Comment: you're trying to assign to  data_filtered.ix 
Should change ix to index

Comment: Update : Upgrading to latest compatible version of Pandas will fix this bug. :)