# Python, Pandas: tz_localize AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time with non DST dates

Tags: python, pandas, timezone, dst

I'm trying to import some timeseries data and convert it into UTC so I can merge it with another dataset. This data seems to have 24 hour data and doesn't have DST adjustments. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068765/python-pandas-tz-localize-throws-nonexistenttimeerror-then-unable-to-drop-erron) gives a similar answer, but they simply drop the line. I need to shift it so I can merge it with my other data.

When I run my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/old_data/nsrdb/1991-2010/data/hourly/{}/{}_{}_solar.csv'.format(723898,723898,1998), usecols=["YYYY-MM-DD", "HH:MM (LST)","Meas Glo (Wh/m^2)","Meas Dir (Wh/m^2)","Meas Dif (Wh/m^2)"])

def clean_time(obj):
    hour = int(obj[0:-3])
    hour = str(hour - 1)
    if len(str(hour)) == 2:
        return hour+":00"
    else:
        return "0" + hour + ":00"

df['HH:MM (LST)'] = df['HH:MM (LST)'].apply(clean_time)
df['DateTime'] = df['YYYY-MM-DD'] + " " + df['HH:MM (LST)']
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['DateTime']))
df.drop(["YYYY-MM-DD", "HH:MM (LST)",'DateTime'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df.index = df.index.tz_localize('US/Pacific', ambiguous='infer')
```

I get:

```
pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from 1998-10-25 01:00:00 as there are no repeated times
```

If I leave ambiguous='raise' (the default), it gives me:

```
pytz.exceptions.NonExistentTimeError: 1998-04-05 02:00:00
```

So I'm stuck on either the start, or end of daylight savings time.

There's quite a few of these datasets (multiple sites over multiple years) I need to merge, so I'd prefer not to hand code specific hours to shift, but I'm still a novice and can't quite figure out my next steps here.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Minimal reproduction scenario:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([[datetime(2019, 10, 27, 0) + timedelta(hours=i), i] for i in range(24)], columns=['dt', 'i']).set_index('dt')
df.index.tz_localize('Europe/Amsterdam', ambiguous='infer')
```

> > > pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from 2019-10-27 02:00:00 as there are no repeated times

Solution: manually specify which datetime objects must be considered DT (Daylight Time) or DST (Daylight Savings Time). See [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([[datetime(2019, 10, 27, 0) + timedelta(hours=i), i] for i in range(24)], columns=['dt', 'i']).set_index('dt')
infer_dst = np.array([False] * df.shape[0])  # all False -> every row considered DT, alternative is True to indicate DST. The array must correspond to the iloc of df.index
df.index.tz_localize('Europe/Amsterdam', ambiguous=infer_dst)  # no error
```