# How to drop a row from Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661701/how-to-drop-a-list-of-rows-from-pandas-dataframe) posted before. However, I want to do something different, here is my `df`:

```
      pos  event
A     4    d5
A     2    d3
B     3    d3
B     6    u3
```

I want to get:

```
      pos  event
A     4    d5
A     2    d3
B     6    u3
```

I wrote this code but it is not working! any suggestion?

```
df.drop(df.ix[B]['event']=='d3', inplace=True)
```

My actual dataframe is big and I want to drop the row that I want with index and value in event column.

Comment: Sorry what are you wanting here? drop all rows with event == 'd3' or all rows with that event and row label B?

Comment: Do you need `print (df[df['event']!='d3'])` ?

Comment: I want to remove the rows with event=='d3' and row label B

Comment: Sorry, I  updated the dataframe, now question should be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `|` (`or`):

```
print (df[(df['event']!='d3') | (df.index != 'B')])
   pos event
A    4    d5
A    2    d3
B    6    u3
```