# How do I remove rows from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove outliers from a dataset. In order to do that, I'm using:

```
df = df[df.attr < df.attr.mean() + df.attr.std()*3]
```

That seems to work as expected, but, when I do something like:

```
for i in xrange(df.shape[0]):
    print df.attr[i]
```

Then I get a `KeyError`. Seems like Pandas isn't actually returning a new `DataFrame` with rows dropped. How do I actually remove those rows, and get a fully functional `DataFrame` back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the indices which meet the criteria (which in your case is df.attr < df.attr.mean() + df.attr.std()*3).

```
x = df.loc[:,attr] < df.attr.mean() + df.attr.std()*3
```

Next, use [DataFrame.drop](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).

```
df.drop(x[x].index)
```

See answers such as [How to drop a list of rows from Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661701/how-to-drop-a-list-of-rows-from-pandas-dataframe) for more information

Answer (score 2):

I think need [`DataFrame.ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
for i in xrange(df.shape[0]):
    print df.ix[i, 'attr']
```

Or [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
for i in xrange(df.shape[0]):
    print df.attr.iloc[i]
```

Simplier solution with [`Series.iteritems`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html):

```
for i, val in df.attr.iteritems():
    print (val)
```

Comment: I'm tempted to accept your answer since it is actually the best solution on my case, but someone Googling those keywords might actually need to drop the rows (for different reasons) so I'll accept the other one.

Comment: I am a bit surprised, I think [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) is better as drop, but it is up to you. good luck :)