# Extracting data frames with equal length from one data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like so:

```
A  | B  | C  | index
-----------------
a1 | b1 | c1 | 1
a2 | b2 | c2 | 2
a3 | b3 | c3 | 3
a4 | b4 | c4 | 4
a5 | b5 | c5 | 5
```

This resembles a time series ordered by the index (or date column if you will)

My goal is to create n data frames with each having 3 entries in order. So the solution would be the following in the above example:

df1)

```
A  | B  | C  | index
-----------------
a1 | b1 | c1 | 1
a2 | b2 | c2 | 2
a3 | b3 | c3 | 3
```

df2)

```
A  | B  | C  | index
-----------------
a2 | b2 | c2 | 2
a3 | b3 | c3 | 3
a4 | b4 | c4 | 4
```

df3)

```
A  | B  | C  | index
-----------------
a3 | b3 | c3 | 3
a4 | b4 | c4 | 4
a5 | b5 | c5 | 5
```

How can I do that in python 3.5 and pandas? In other languages I would probably take a for loop and iterate over i in range(1,len(df)-2), but I am guessing there is a much more pythonic solution to this.

Thanks in advance for your help!! :-)

Comment: may be this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661701/how-to-drop-a-list-of-rows-from-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Do you actually need the three data frames, or are you interested in computing aggregated values from each of the three?  If the latter, consider using [`rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html).

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I need three data frames as I consider each data frame as one example of a time series to train a machine learning algorithm on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still using for loop :

```
variables = locals()
for i in range(1,4):
    variables["df{0}".format(i)] = df.loc[(df['index']>=i)&(df['index']<=i+2),]
```

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that a for loop is the only answer then?

Comment: @LukasHestermeyer or you can look at `shift`