# Drop rows by index from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an array `wrong_indexes_train` which contains a list of indexes that I would like to remove from a dataframe:

```
[0, 63, 151, 469, 1008]
```

To remove these indexes, I am trying this:

```
df_train.drop(wrong_indexes_train)
```

However, the code fails with the error:

```
ValueError: labels ['OverallQual' 'GrLivArea' 'GarageCars' 'TotalBsmtSF' 'FullBath'
 'YearBuilt'] not contained in axis
```

Here, `['OverallQual' 'GrLivArea' 'GarageCars' 'TotalBsmtSF' 'FullBath' 'YearBuilt']` are the names of my dataframe's columns.

How could I just make the dataframe drop the entire rows of the indices that I specified?

Comment: Have a look at this. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html
"Specifying both labels and index or columns will raise a ValueError."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Change it to

```
df_train.drop(wrong_indexes_train,axis=1)
```

Comment: Actually, it's `axis=1` because I'm  removing rows, not columns, but I figured out looking at your answer.

Comment: That's what I had at first then I edited it after the documentation said otherwise. Glad I could help. axis : int or axis name

Whether to drop labels from the index (0 / ‘index’) or columns (1 / ‘columns’).

Comment: i thought drop(rownumber) will drop row = rownumber.  axis =1 means column.  What is this dropping?

Comment: The above seems a bit confusing; axis=1 would indeed drop columns, so axis=0 or axis='index' would be the way to drop rows. Correct approach, but need to set that parameter correctly based on the use case.

Answer (score 11):

Not 100% certain what you want without a minimum-(not)working-example, but you should specify an `axis` parameter.  `df.drop` returns the modified `DataFrame`.  If you want to operate inplace, specify `inplace=True`.

See this for symbolic row names (index):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ones":[1,3,5],
                   "tens":[20, 40, 60]},
                  index=['barb', 'mark', 'ethan'])
df.drop(['barb', 'mark'], axis='index')
```

And this for numeric (default) indices:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ones":[1,3,5],
                   "tens":[20, 40, 60]})
df.drop([0,2], axis='index')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
df_train=df_train.reset_index()
```

followed by

```
df_train.drop(wrong_indexes_train)
```

My guess is `df_train` doesn't have a numerical index right now, rather one of the columns `['OverallQual' 'GrLivArea' 'GarageCars' 'TotalBsmtSF' 'FullBath' 'YearBuilt']` is serving as the index.

Comment: Please consider editing this to add in code blocks, it would greatly improve readability.

Comment: index refers to rows, not columns.

Answer (score 0):

One can use drop [`DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas-dataframe-drop) for that.

Considering that one wants to drop the rows, one should use `axis=0` or `axis='index'`. If one wants to drop columns, `axis=1` or `axis='columns'`.

For your specific case, one can do

```
wrong_indexes_train = [0, 63, 151, 469, 1008]

df_train.drop(wrong_indexes_train, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

or

```
df_train.drop(df_train[[0, 63, 151, 469, 1008]], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

One can also select the rows with [`DataFrame.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html)

```
wrong_indexes_train = df_train.index[[0, 63, 151, 469, 1008]]

df_train.drop(wrong_indexes_train, inplace=True)
```

On another hand, and assuming that one's dataframe and the rows to drop are considerably big, one might want to consider selecting the rows to keep (as [Dennis Golomazov suggests here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43421391/7109869)). For that, one might use [Mad Physicist's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67572464/7109869):

```
import numpy as np

wrong_indexes_train = [0, 63, 151, 469, 1008]

mask = np.ones((len(df_train), bool)

mask = df_train.iloc[wrong_indexes_train] = False

df_train_new = df_train.iloc[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

To drop one or multiple rows use axis=0:

```
wrong_indexes_train = [0, 63, 151, 469, 1008] # your indexes
df_train.drop(wrong_indexes_train, axis=0, inplace=True)
```