# How do I create a function that will accept a pandas dataframe and remove rows containing a specific value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, function, dataframe

I am looking to create a function that will accept a pandas dataframe and a specific value(to_drop) which will then remove any row containing the specified value.

For example if I have this dataframe:

```
d = {'Name': ['John', 'Bill', "Frank"], 'A' : [1, 5, 7], 'B': [2, 0, 6], 'C' : [3, 1, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

If the specific value I choose is 0, the function should remove Bill's row returning the rows of John and Frank.

I am trying to use:

```
def drop_row(df, to_drop):
    new_df = df[df.column != to_drop]
    return new_df
```

This is resulting in an attribute error, which I assumed it would because this only works when you are choosing a specific column.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop rows by index from dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47932937/drop-rows-by-index-from-dataframe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) or [`pandas.DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) along `axis=1` on the condition:

```
>>> df[df.ne(0).all(1)]
    Name  A  B  C
0   John  1  2  3
2  Frank  7  6  9

>>> df[~df.eq(0).any(1)]
    Name  A  B  C
0   John  1  2  3
2  Frank  7  6  9
```

You can make a function out of this, but frankly, it's unnnecessary:

```
>>> drop_row = lambda df: df[~df.eq(0).any(1)]
>>> drop_row(df)
    Name  A  B  C
0   John  1  2  3
2  Frank  7  6  9
```

It checks for the condition:

```
>>> df.ne(0) # items (n)ot (e)qual to 0:
   Name     A      B     C
0  True  True   True  True
1  True  True  False  True
2  True  True   True  True

>>> df.ne(0).all(1)  # checks if all values along axis 1 are True
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool

>>> df[df.ne(0).all(1)]  # Returns only index where values is True (i.e. 0, 2)
    Name  A  B  C
0   John  1  2  3
2  Frank  7  6  9
```

Comment: Just a thought if OP had columns with other dtypes, use `df.select_dtypes(include=np.number)` for comparison then.

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn the tools to implement the logic you already have.  The missing piece is the `any` and `all` functions.  Look up how to iterate over selected columns of a DF.  Put that into a list comprehension expression.  Then apply `any` to that.  The filtering syntax (as opposed to using the `drop` method) will look something like

```
df[ all( [df.column != to_drop for column ...] ) ]
```

I'll leave the iteration syntax up to your research.

Answer (score 1):

Define your function as:

```
def drop_row(df, to_drop):
    return df[~df.eq(to_drop).any(axis=1)]
```

Then if you call e.g. `drop_row(df, 1)`, you will get:

```
    Name  A  B  C
2  Frank  7  6  9
```

i.e. row with index == 0 and 1, both containing *1* in any column,
are dropped.