# Call multiple Rows in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to drop multiple rows from my data.
I can drop rows using:

```
dt=dt.drop([40,41,42,43,44,45])
```

But I was wondering if there is a simpler way. I tried:

```
dt=dt.drop([40:45])
```

But sadly it did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drop a list of rows from Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661701/how-to-drop-a-list-of-rows-from-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: This has already been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661701/how-to-drop-a-list-of-rows-from-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will recommend `np.r_`

```
df.drop(np.r_[40:50+1])
```

In case you want to drop two range at the same time

```
np.r_[40:50+1,1:4+1]
Out[719]: array([40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50,  1,  2,  3,  4])
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to drop a range of positions:

```
df.drop(df.index[40: 46])
```

This doesn't assume the indices are integers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
dt = dt.drop(range(40,46))
```

or

```
dt.drop(range(40,46), inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the list based on a range:

```
dt=dt.drop([x for x in range(40, 46)])
```

Or just:

```
dt=dt.drop(range(40, 46))
```