# Pandas Dataframe Drop both records and their duplicates

Tags: python-3.x

I want drop records that have duplicates and their duplicates in pandas Dataframe based on a column

Comment: Please post sample data, expected output and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drop a list of rows from Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661701/how-to-drop-a-list-of-rows-from-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @abhlib : user is asking how to remove duplicate column , not rows i believe and also how to drop with condition. I assume he is not aware which all columsn are duplicate. So he is not aware of the index of the columns to be dropped.

Comment: @nitin3685 i think abhilb ia actually quite on track....however am not only looking to drop the duplicates, I want to drop both the duplicate and the first instance of the record.(Drop both the record and its duplicate)--drop both rows keep that in mind....

Comment: @herbert : use `drop_duplicated` with `keep=False` as mentioned my answer . If you want to drop duplicate rows, don't use `.T`

Comment: @herbert : Please check the updated answer. It allows you to drop duplicate records based on a subset of columns and drops both the record and its duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='column_name',keep=False)
```

`drop_duplicates` will drop duplicated

`subset` will allow you the specify based on which column you want to determine duplicated

`keep` will allow you to specify which record to keep or drop.

[drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) : Please check this link for more info.