# Remove rows from dataset in python

Tags: python, isolation-forest

I'm trying to take some rows that are classified as outliers, and remove these rows from the original dataset, but I can't make it work - do you guys know what goes wrong? I try to run the followin code, and get this error "ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional"

```
#identify outliers
pred = iforest.fit_predict(x)
outlier_index = np.where(pred==-1)
outlier_values = x.iloc[outlier_index]
#remove from dataset (dataset = x)
x_new = x.drop([outlier_values])
```

[outlier_values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWx5v.png)
[original dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYXUH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outlier_values you linked is a dataframe not a flat list of indexes, so the value error is thrown accordingly.

What you need to do is to extract the list of indexes from the outlier_values dataframe, using:

```
index_list = outlier_values.index.values.tolist()
```

into a list of indexes and then drop those indexes from x.

as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14661768/10943635) answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#identify outliers
pred = iforest.fit_predict(x)

# np.where returns a tuple of ndarray we access the first dimension
outlier_index = np.where(pred==-1)[0] 

outlier_values = x.iloc[outlier_index]

#remove from dataset (dataset = x)
x_new = x.drop([outlier_values])
```

In your case you could directly pass `outlier_index` as so

```
#identify outliers
pred = iforest.fit_predict(x)
outlier_index = np.where(pred==-1)[0]
df = df.drop(outlier_index)
```