# Can't figure out why my panda's drop method doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, pandas

Have pandas DF of type:

```
          state    x    y
0          Alabama  139  -77
1           Alaska -204 -170
2          Arizona -203  -40
etc.
```

I have a list of state names which I need to remove from this DF. I try to use loop for it, but it does not work and the DF is the same as before. The state names are what they need to be, so they should be found by my condition.

```
for state in self.guessed_states:
    states_data.drop(states_data[states_data["state"] == state].index, inplace=True)
```

The output is the same, so nothing changes after this loop. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: states_data = states_data.query(expr="state not in @self.guessed_states")

Comment: Try: `states_data = states_data[~states_data["state"].isin(self.guessed_states)]`

Comment: several variable names are left for us to guess what they are. You could work your question closer to an actual [MRVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Would you mind posting `self.guessed_states`  and relevant rows of `states_data.to_dict(),` so we may fully reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

`Drop()` or `filter` in dataframe can be used like:

```
import pandas as pd

del_ = ['Drop1','Drop2']

data = {'state':['Alabama','Alaska','Drop2','Arizona','Drop1'], 'x':[139,-204,-100,-203,'--100']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Filter to searched row in del_ list
df3 = df[df['state'].isin(del_)]
print(df3)

# Filter to searched row not in del_ list
df4 = df[~df['state'].isin(del_)]
print(df4)


# drop() row by cell value
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['state'] in del_:
        df = df.drop(i)       
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     state      x
0  Alabama    139
1   Alaska   -204
2    Drop2   -100
3  Arizona   -203
4    Drop1  --100

   state      x
2  Drop2   -100
4  Drop1  --100

     state     x
0  Alabama   139
1   Alaska  -204
3  Arizona  -203

     state     x
0  Alabama   139
1   Alaska  -204
3  Arizona  -203
```

Other drop solutions are:

```
# Methods - Using the drop() function
# remove from existing df
df.drop(df.index[df['state'] == 'Drop1'], inplace=True)

# remove and show in new df
df2 = df.drop(df[df['state'] == 'Drop2'].index, axis=0)
print(df2)
```

Comment: This is a curious way to use drop. In a loop when the function readily accepts multiple rows, and... do I see deleting elements from the object you are iterating on?

Comment: @OCa I don’t know, if I understood your request right. Edited my first solution and add further functions. Hope this helps.

Comment: Anyways. I was mostly curious why you would indulge in using for loop for drop. I suppose this is for the sake of explaning.

Answer (score -1):

Your loop actually works as you would expect on my side, when I use a list of states of my own. This suggests that your `self.guessed_states` does not in fact contain states names exactly as they appear in the input dataframe. It may be empty, could be different case a/A, or trailing spaces?

Directly answering to "What am I doing wrong here?" will be difficult until you include a print of `self.guessed_states` in your question.

Now, I can't help pointing out that your code could be quite simpler, since really there is absolutely no need for a `for` loop here. Below are another way ot use `drop`, then another alternative.

**1. Using `drop`**

If you would like to use index tools such as drop, you could just as easily set the states as index:

```py
df = states_data.set_index('state')
           x    y
state            
Alabama  139  -77
Alaska  -204 -170
Arizona -203  -40
```

At this point [How to drop a list of rows from Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661701/how-to-drop-a-list-of-rows-from-pandas-dataframe) has your answer: `drop` is straightforward, since it readily accepts lists:

```py
drop_list = ['Alabama','Arizona']

df.drop(drop_list, axis=0, inplace=True)
          x    y
state           
Alaska -204 -170
```

You may restore the dataframe's original shape any time:

```py
df.reset_index(drop=False)
    state    x    y
0  Alaska -204 -170
```

**2. Alternatively**, if you wish to keep the dataframe structure at all times, as not_speshal also suggested in a comment, you may also directly use the one-liner below, which will return the same output:

```
states_data[~states_data['state'].isin(drop_list)]
```