# How to drop rows in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I tried to use `df.iloc` to remove columns and rows. It worked for columns but is not working for rows. I just want to remove the first two rows of the csv file. What am I missing???

```
benz1 = benz.drop(benz.iloc[:,0:10],axis = 1) # Worked
benz2 = benz1.drop(benz1.iloc[0:1,:], axis = 0) # Did not work
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661701/how-to-drop-a-list-of-rows-from-pandas-dataframe

Comment: why not `just benz.iloc[2:, 2:]`?

Comment: "did not work" is insufficient to characterize a problem to be solved by your SO fellows. Don't leave us guessing. In this case, though, let me guess: it removed only the first row. Please confirm, by printing your output in your question

Comment: `df.drop` takes **labels**, not values. So what the heck is your data that it worked for columns? Please make a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: After reading the answers, I now see why it worked for columns, but I still want to see an example with example data, desired output, and actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

- Been there, done that: `0:1` stands for `range(0,1)`, which, as you probably know, starts *and* stops at 0. Instead, `0:2` will yield your desired (0,1) sequence that would point to the 2 first rows.
- Are you comfortable with what arguments a [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) actually takes? `DataFrame.drop(labels=None, *, axis=0, index=None, columns=None, level=None, inplace=False, errors='raise')`

---

Alternative syntaxes:

Since you required dropping rows by their position, using argument `index` makes sense, but you can also use `labels` while specifying the `axis`:

```
# Drop the 2 first rows
benz1.drop(labels=[0,1], axis=0)
# Equivalent:
benz1.drop(index=[0,1])
```

or, using a range,

```
# Drop the 2 first rows
benz1.drop(index=range(2))
```

or, arguably the most pythonic:

```
# Drop the 2 first rows
benz1.iloc[2:]
# Equivalent when specifying only row indices:
benz1[2:]
```

---

Now why did your first line (dropping the 10 first columns, was it?) somehow work as intended?

You gave as argument `benz.iloc[:,0:10]`, which is a dataframe. But because Pandas is nice like that, your line was interpreted as dropping the *labels* of the columns *present* in the passed dataframe:

```
benz.drop(labels=benz.iloc[:,0:10], axis = 1) # Worked
# Equivalent
benz.drop(columns=benz.iloc[:,0:10])
```

---

Finally:

```
# Drop the 2 first rows and the 10 first columns at once:
benz.iloc[2:,10:]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the first parameter for [pd.DataFrame.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) is labels.  Either column labels or index labels.

When dropping with axis=1 (dropping columns), you can pass it a dataframe which pandas turns it into what looks like a list of columns.

When dropping with axis=0 (default behavior dropping rows), you need to pass a list of index labels. However, when passing in your filter dataframe (by rows) pandas is still turning this into a list of columns which isn't matching the index label list.
Hence you're getting KeyError.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,24, (5,5)), index=[*'abcde'], columns=[*'ABCDE'])

df.drop(df.iloc[:,[2,4]], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   D
a  15  15   8
b  23  16  13
c  14  14  10
d  19  19   7
e  11   2  20
```

To fix this you can use .T to transpose your filter dataframe such that it returns a list of index labels.

```
df.drop(df.iloc[[2,4],:].T)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
a   3   1  10  19  20
b  13  15   8  13   3
d  20  13   4  14  17
```

Note, this is not the standard to drop rows, it is best to just past a list of index labels.

Answer (score 0):

```
benz2 = benz1.drop(index=[0,1], axis=0)
```

or if you dont need to store in `benz2` and delete from `benz1` then use below

```
benz1.drop(index=[0,1], axis=0, inplace=True)
```

and check `benz1` on next line